Code a for loop that runs through all numbers from 0-99 and append all numbers divisible by seven into a string. Return this string
I am trying some JavaScript challenges and I cam across this question "Code a for loop that runs through all numbers from 0-99 and append all numbers divisible by seven into a string. Return this string". The expected outcome is
'0714212835424956637077849198'
My first solution was
enter image description here
function easyLoop() {
var result = "";
for(var i = 0; i < 99;  i++){
if(i % 7 === 0){
  result = result + i;
}
}
  console.log("'" + result + "'");
  
}
easyLoop();

The outcome of my solution was '0714212835424956637077849198' my code wouldn't go through.

The second solution I tried was
enter image description here
function easyLoop() {
var result = "";
for(var i = 0; i < 99;  i++){
if(i % 7 === 0){
  result = result + i;
}
}
 console.log(result.toString());
  
}
easyLoop();

The outcome of my solution was 0714212835424956637077849198 my code wouldn't go through.
Any suggest of what the problem might be?

"Return this string" - return, not log to console.

You might want to add a return statement at the end of your function so it returns a string as mentioned in problem question
    function easyLoop() {
    let result = "";

      for(let i = 0; i < 99;  i++)
        if(i%7 === 0)
          result += i.toString();
    
      return result;
    }

    console.log(easyLoop());


Thank you very much @mrstronk, the code worked.
